# SOLR - Combining block join phrase queries using OR

Tags: solr, lucene

How to do an OR between two block join clauses .

for example : I want to find all parent documents who has the phrases "abc def" OR "hij lmn"

Assumption here being "abc def " and "hij lmn" are in different child docs and all parent docs have an identifier doc_type:parent

Logically , the query would be:

`({!parent which="doc_type:parent"}"abc def") OR ({!parent which="doc_type:parent"}"hij lmn")` .
This query would throw the

> **EOF .org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse '\"abc': Lexical**
>   **error at line 1, column 5.**

Encountered:  after : **\"\\"abc\""error .**

I cannot combine with fq's because i have an OR operator here . How do we solve this ?

Comment: hi could you please provide the full query here.

Comment: The same query i'd posted in the question , Pasting again for your reference : ({!parent which="doc_type:parent"}"abc def") OR ({!parent which="doc_type:parent"}"hij lmn")

Comment: Hello , Any updates on the answer ? Am quite stuck on this .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue has been answered by Yonik Seeley at the following link 
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.jakarta.lucene.solr.user/95646

Quoting the answer for ease :
({!parent which="doc_type:parent" v=' "abc def" '})
OR 
({!parent which="doc_type:parent" v=' "hij lmn" '})

Answer (score 2):

try with single space after the block join construct 
e.g
({!parent which="doc_type:parent"} "abc def") OR ({!parent which="doc_type:parent"} "hij lmn")

Comment: This solution would solve the syntax issue . But the query result being returned is wrong